# Python how to shorten import path

Tags: python, import

My Project looks like this:

```
├─outer_module
│  │  __init__.py
│  │
│  └─inner_module
│          a.py
│          b.py
├─test.py
```

`__init__.py`:

```py
from outer_module.inner_module import a
from outer_module.inner_module import b
```

`a.py`:

```py
instance_a = 1
```

`b.py`:

```py
instance_b = 1
print("instance_b created!")
```

`test.py`:

```py
from outer_module.inner_module import a
```

I want to shorten import path in `test.py`, i.e. use `from outer_module import a`. That is not unusual when I turn my project into a release module. But using `__init__.py`, it will automatically invoke `b.py` and print `instance_b created!`. Seperating `a.py` and `b.py` from inner_module is not recommended because they are functionally similar. Other .py file may invoke `b.py` so `b.py` must appear in `__init__.py`
Could anyone give some advice?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder

Answer (score 0):

In your `__init__.py` file try importing the a and b files individually and adding the two imports to your `__all__` variable.

```
from outer_module.inner_module import a
from outer_module.inner_module import b 

__all__ = [
    'a',
    'b',
]
```

Now you can import a and b directly from outer_module.

```
from outermodule import a
import outermodule.b as b
```

Comment: Still print `instance_b created!`. In `test.py` I only want to import a. But using `__init__.py` will automatically run b.py. Anyway thanks!

Comment: What about adding a __init__ file to inner_module?